# How to build RESTful request over in java

Tags: java, rest, http

I tried to understand how to send REST request to server. If I have to implement this as a request in java using httpconnections or any other connections, how would I do that?

```
    POST /resource/1
    Host: myownHost
    DATE: date
    Content-Type: some standard type
```

How should this be structured in a standard way?

```
    URL url= new URL("http://myownHost/resource/1");
    HttpsURLConnection connect= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connect.setRequestProperty("Host", "myOwnHost");
    connect.setRequestProperty("Date","03:14:15 03:14:15 GMT");
    connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: [FYI](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/)

Comment: Usually you let the http client (i.e. the URL class) set the "host" and "date" headers. Unless you want to specifically override those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options, Apache HTTP client (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/index.html) is one of them (and makes things very easy)

Creating REST requests can be as easy as this (using JSON in this case):

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
        "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/get");
    getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
           + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                     new   InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
```

Update: Sorry the link to the documentation was updated.Posted the new one.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `json` here

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientPost {

// http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    URL url = new URL("http://myownHost/resource/1");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String input = "{\"DATE\":\"03:14:15 03:14:15 GMT\",\"host\":\"myownhost\"}";

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

   } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

 }

}
```

more over it browse [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to call a RESTful service with Java but it's not required to use raw level APIs ;-)

It exists some RESTful frameworks like Restlet or JAX-RS. They address both client and server side and aim to hide the technical plumbing of such calls. Here is a sample of code describing how to do your processing with Restlet and a JSON parser:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("host", "...");
ClientResource cr = new Client("http://myownHost/resource/1");
cr.post(new JsonRepresentation(jsonObject);

// In the case of form
// Form form = new Form ();
// form.set("host", "...");
// cr.post(form);
```

You can notice that in the previous snippet, headers `Content-type`, `Date` are automatically set for you based on what you sent (form, JSON, ...)

Otherwise a small remark, to add an element you should use a method `POST` on the element list resource (`http://myownHost/resources/`) or a method `PUT` if you have the unique identifier you want to use to identify it (`http://myownHost/resources/1`). This link could be useful to you: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry